# Stieltjes Integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha$ be Stieltjes weight function (monotone increasing), and $\alpha = \alpha_1+\alpha_2$, where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are also monotone increasing. suppose $f$ is Stieltjes-integrable on $[a,b]$

$$\int_a^bf d\alpha = \int_a^b f d\alpha_1 + \int_a^b f d\alpha_2$$

Under what conditions is this statement true? How can I prove it easily using basic knowledge of upper and lower Stieltjes integral? If it is not true all the time counter examples?

Comment: It should be sufficient that measure $\alpha(M)= \alpha_1(M) + \alpha_2(M)$.

Comment: I didn't learn measure yet, just in the basic analysis course

Comment: Try to show that $\alpha(M) = \text{inf}\{ \sum_i \alpha(I_i): M\subset \bigcup_i I_i\} = \text{inf}\{ \sum_i \alpha_1(I_i): M\subset \bigcup_i I_i\} +  \text{inf}\{ \sum_i \alpha_2(I_i): M\subset \bigcup_i I_i\} = \alpha_1(M) +\alpha_2(M) $.

Where $I$ are intervals of type $ (c,d] $. Plus functions $\alpha,\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ should be right continuous.

$\alpha((c,d]) = \alpha(d) - \alpha(c) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\uint{\overline{\int_a^b}}\newcommand\lint{\underline{\int_a^b}}$

## Notations

Suppose $\alpha$ is monotone increasing on $[a,b]$, $P=\{\,x_0,x_1,\dotsc,x_n\,\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, where $a=x_0\le x_1\le\dotsb\le x_n=b$, $f$ is a bounded function on $[a,b]$, we'll use notations here:

\begin{align}
&\Delta\alpha_k=\alpha(x_k)-\alpha(x_{k-1})\\\\
&M_k=\sup_{x_{k-1}\le x\le x_k}f(x)
&m_k=\inf_{x_{k-1}\le x\le x_k}f(x)\\
&U(P,f,\alpha)=\sum_{k=1}^nM_k\Delta\alpha_k
&L(P,f,\alpha)=\sum_{k=1}^nm_k\Delta\alpha_k\\
&\uint fd\alpha=\inf_P U(P,f,\alpha)
&\lint fd\alpha=\sup_P U(P,f,\alpha)
\end{align}

## Stronger results

\begin{align}
\uint fd(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)&=\uint fd\alpha_1+\uint fd\alpha_2\\
\lint fd(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)&=\lint fd\alpha_1+\lint fd\alpha_2
\end{align}

## Proof

We'll only prove the first one. For each partition $P$, it's easier to check that
$$U(P,f,\alpha_1+\alpha_2)=U(P,f,\alpha_1)+U(P,f,\alpha_2)$$
Take $\inf_P$ on both sides, we have
$$\uint fd(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)\ge\uint fd\alpha_1+\uint fd\alpha_2$$

Next, for each $u_1>\uint fd\alpha_1$, $u_2>\uint fd\alpha_2$, there's some partitons $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that $U(P_1,f,\alpha_1)<u_1$ and $U(P_2,f,\alpha_2)<u_2$.

Consider $P=P_1\cup P_2$, we have $U(P,f,\alpha_1)\le U(P_1,f,\alpha_1)<u_1$ and $U(P,f,\alpha_2)<u_2$, then
$$U(P,f,\alpha_1+\alpha_2)=U(P,f,\alpha_1)+U(P,f,\alpha_2)<u_1+u_2$$
therefore
$$\uint fd(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)<u_1+u_2$$

Hence
$$\uint fd(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)\le\uint fd\alpha_1+\uint fd\alpha_2$$

Proved.

Comment: Very good proof. thanks.

Comment: Your proof partially finishes my question. I have further question, what if now we only assume that $f$ is stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha = \alpha_1+\alpha_2$, and only that $\alpha_1$,$\alpha_2$ are monotone increasing bounded functions, can we deduce $$\int_a^b f d\alpha = \int_a^b f d\alpha_1 +\int_a^b f d\alpha_2$$? We are not sure whether $$\overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha_1 = \underline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha_1$$, is it true to begin with?

Comment: @mezhang According to the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Stieltjes_integral#Generalized_Riemann.E2.80.93Stieltjes_integral), $\uint fd\alpha=\lint fd\alpha$ if and only if $f\in\mathcal R(\alpha)$, i.e. integrable (according to $\alpha$).

Comment: This I know, but how does $\overline{\int}_a^b f d(\alpha_1+\alpha_2) = \underline{\int}_a^b f d(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$ imply $\overline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha_1 = \underline{\int}_a^b f d\alpha_1$?

Comment: @mezhang Since $\uint fd\alpha_1+\uint fd\alpha_2=\int_a^bfd(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)=\lint fd\alpha_1+\lint fd\alpha_2$, and $\uint fd\alpha_k\ge\lint fd\alpha_k$, so $\uint fd\alpha_k=\lint fd\alpha_k$ for $k=1,2$.

Comment: I should have seen that. Thanks.